# How to do summation based on the value

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a csv file, when I do

```
df["CATEGORY"].value_counts()
```

I want the result (the summation) to be grouped into 3 groups:

```
names start with "CONDO"
names start with "RENTALS"
everything else can fall under "other": (the value should be
```

how can I write the code?

Comment: Please provide the generating code for the dataframe, otherwise it is unnecessarily difficult to test our implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add another column to your dataframe, then

```
df["type"] = ["CONDO" if name.startswith("CONDO") else "RENTAL" if name.startswith("RENTAL") else "OTHER" for name in df.CATEGORY]
df.groupby("type").sum()
```

will give you your desired result.